# How do i create a modal box for each wordpress post in a foreach loop?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

I hope some of you can help me with this, as it is the last thing i need to complete my project for my last exam.
I am creating a custom wordpress theme, where i am showing all my posts using a foreach loop. Right now, only a div box with a thumbnail picture, the creation date and title are showing for each post, but i want to be able to open a modal box here you can read the post description, when you click a image.
Of course the correct modal box should open according to which post you click.

Right now only the newest post is opening in a modal box.

My code right now looks like this

HTML

```
<div id="frontNews">
  <h2 class="center">NYHEDER</h2>
   <div class="news-list">
    <?php $latest_post = get_posts( 'numberposts=4' ); ?>
    <?php foreach( $latest_post as $post ) : setup_postdata( $post ); ?
>
          <?php $thumb = wp_get_attachment_image_src( 
get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), 'full' );?>
           <div class="news-post" id="myBtn">
           <div class="thumbnail-img" style="background-image: url('<?
php echo $thumb['0'];?>')">
           <div class="black">
           <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
           <div class="news-headline">
           <small class="time"><?php the_time('j. F Y') ?></small>
           <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
            </div>
               </div>
               </div>
           </div>
           <div id="myModal" class="modal">

            <!-- Modal content -->
            <div class="modal-content">
            <span class="close">&times;</span>
            <p>Some text in the Modal..</p>
          </div>

        </div>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    <?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
   </div>
```

Javascript

```
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');

var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");

var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

btn.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "block";
}

span.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "none";
}

window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (event.target == modal) {
        modal.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

Comment: can you post html for model and jquery?

Comment: You should do some research first - have you tried to google how modal boxes work?. This question sounds like "implement this for me please" which is off-topic - see [what topics can I ask about](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: Just edited the post :-)